# How to add a custiomized javascipt into a template

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie of Wordpress. Now I am trying to add my av_s.js file into a Wordpress template, but it seems much more crappy than I expected.

I locate the av_s.js file in the js folder under my theme, and declare it in the function.php like this:

```
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'av_s', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/av_s.js', array('jquery') 
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

and have a code like:

```
<script src='./wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/av_s.js'> </script>
```

...in the head part of the header.php in my theme.

But all the efforts do NOT work, I am really out of ideas. Any help and hint are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Register the script first, then ask WP to enqueue it :

```
function add_my_script() {
   wp_register_script('av_s', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/av_s.js', array('jquery'));
   wp_register_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'),'1', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('av_s');
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Returns in `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{sitename}/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/av_s.js?ver={version}"></script>
```

Comment: hi,samuel, thanks for your answers, but I am afraid that it does not work either.

Comment: I tested it, it worked. What is your site ?

Comment: In fact, my first attempt is to write the javascript/jQuery in the "Text"-mode of editing my page(in the dashboard directly), and I failed. Then I wonder, the javascript may be supposed to be located in the <head> part. so I move this part of script into an individual file "av_s.js" and wish to recall it in my editing page. But the dilemma is that both ways fail...Do you have further suggestions please? Thanks again.

Comment: I see. but, did you place the above code in your functions.php file ? because I did and it enqueued the script in my site header. if the script is Jquery don't forget to enqueue this one as well `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js` without it jquery won't work..

Comment: I should be more clear. I found out that the .js files in the js folder are all written in jQuery, but my script uses the grammars of javascript. So may this cause some problems? And in this case, where should I find my version details please? Thanks!

Comment: I see. then enqueue the googleapis url as well. editing the answer in light of this new need.

Comment: I have edited the answer. try to enqueue the above code in your functions.php and come back for feed-backs

Comment: It failed as well.

Comment: "it failed" means ? you checked `<head></head>` of your site and couldn't find the scripts enqueued OR the scripts didn't work ?

Comment: I put the codes like this in the function.php:function my_jquery_enqueue()
{
wp_deregister_script(`jquery');
wp_register_script(`jquery','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js',false,null);
wp_enqueue_script(`jquery');
}

add_action(`wp_enqueue_script','my_jquery_enqueue');

Comment: Sorry, I sent the comment before I have edited it carelessly:).

Comment: Please paste the code as in above ( I have no idea what wp_deregister_script stands for ) and check your <head> if the scripts are there ( go to the source code, and ctrl+f search for av_s and you shall find it ).

Comment: Yes!! I have viewed the page source, and the av_s.js is in the <head> part(I don't append the version information of javascript in the header.php since I don't know it, but I have tried with the 1.11.1...). P.S. I just google how to enqueue the jquery, and I copy their codes, wondering the "deregister" may deresister the older version of jquery if it is necessary.